# Cairo image blurred when scaled

Tags: c, gtk, cairo

I have the following cairo code:

```
cairo_set_source_rgba(cr, 1, 1, 1, 1);
cairo_rectangle(cr, 0, 0, WINDOW_SIZE, WINDOW_SIZE);
cairo_fill(cr);
cairo_scale(cr, 8, 8);
draw_image(cr, "q.png", 5, 5);
```

And

```
void draw_image(cairo_t* cr, char* img_name, int x, int y)
{
    cairo_translate(cr, x, y);
    cairo_surface_t* img = cairo_image_surface_create_from_png(img_name);
    cairo_set_source_surface(cr, img, 0, 0);
    cairo_paint(cr);
    cairo_translate(cr, -x, -y);
}
```

q.png is a 5x5 image:
[image]

But when the program is run, the image is slightly blurred:
[image]

I have already tried

```
cairo_set_antialias(cr, CAIRO_ANTIALIAS_NONE);
```

but it does not work.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Comment: This is because of how the image is scaled up. Instead of setting a source surface directly, create a pattern out of the surface with `cairo_pattern_create_for_surface()`, call `cairo_pattern_set_filter()` on it to set the scaling mode, and then call `cairo_set_source()` to load the pattern. See the documentation for `cairo_filter_t` for the scaling modes. `CAIRO_FILTER_NEAREST`, for example, will give you a normal pixel zoom with no blurring or other transformations.

Comment: Using `CAIRO_FILTER_NEAREST` worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of how the image is scaled up. Instead of setting a source surface directly, create a pattern out of the surface with `cairo_pattern_create_for_surface()`, call `cairo_pattern_set_filter()` on it to set the scaling mode, and then call `cairo_set_source()` to load the pattern. See the documentation for `cairo_filter_t` for the scaling modes. `CAIRO_FILTER_NEAREST`, for example, will give you a normal pixel zoom with no blurring or other transformations.